# How to create non-blocking QMessageBox in Pyside?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, concurrency, pyside

I am trying to create a simple non-blocking QMessageBox using PySide. Unfortunately, the qmessagebox is not showing up. I have tried following examples from C and adapting the code but so far nothing is working. Here is my code:

```
import PySide.QtGui as qg
import PySide
widget = qg.QMessageBox()
widget.setText("Close Gazebo to continue...")
widget.setWindowModality(PySide.QtCore.Qt.NonModal)    
widget.show()
#Do some computationally expensive stuff...
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there anything else I need to ensure the window is non-blocking and properly appears? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In your real code, are you keeping a reference to the messagebox? If you allow it to go out of scope, it will just get garbage-collected immediately after it's shown. (Alternatively, you could give it a parent, and then Qt will keep it alive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you haven't defined the QApplication.

```
import PySide.QtGui as qg
import PySide.QtCore as qc
import sys

app = qg.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = qg.QMessageBox()
widget.setText("Close Gazebo to continue...")
widget.setWindowModality(qc.Qt.NonModal)    
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

There are a few changes I made. First:

```
import PySide.QtCore as qc
...
widget.setWindowModality(qc.Qt.NonModal)
```

This removed the `import PySide` and instead just imported `QtCore`. It's not a huge change, but follows your import for `QtGui`.

```
import sys

app = qg.QApplication(sys.argv)
...
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

These are the lines that are important. This sets up a [`QApplication`](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QApplication.html).

> PySide.QtGui.QApplication contains the main event loop, where all events from the window system and other sources are processed and dispatched. It also handles the application’s initialization, finalization, and provides session management. In addition, PySide.QtGui.QApplication handles most of the system-wide and application-wide settings.

---

The code above, produces this window:

[image: Example window]

Comment: I should have specified but I already have an application running and I want to open an additional window. I apologize for not specifying it. In this sense, what is the issue I need to open an additional window do I need to open another app object?

Comment: No you do not need another app object. You'll have to provide a bit more context in your question though, unfortunately. I suspect there is something else preventing that widget from being displayed if you already have a larger application. With the code you provided, it was just the missing `QApplication` (you do already have that, correct?)

Comment: Yes, I do. The Widget just does not display. Here is link to the full [codebase](https://github.com/Skylion007/popupcad/blob/master/popupcad_gazebo/gazebo_controller.py) if you need more context. The widget is in the apply_joint_forces method

Comment: I only see PySide imported in that single file (with code that you've pasted above). You do not have another `QApplication` object. Try adding the code I have above and see if that solves your problem, since this would be the first (and only) QApplication - and PySide application

Comment: On a side note, you should add `*.py[cod]` to your `.gitignore` and remove your `.pyc` files from the repository. You don't need to (or want) to include those since they will get regenerated automatically when you execute your scripts.

Comment: I have the application in popupcad.py which is the "main" class of the application.

Comment: In conclusion, I just needed to know the difference between a dialog versus an entirely new window.

Answer (score 0):

You must do the computationally expensive stuff in a separate thread, and let the event loop run in the main thread. Or do the expensive stuff while occasionally executing `QCoreApplication.processEvents()`.